# Ansible. AWS EC2. Как выполнить task после создания instance?

Tags: ansible, amazon-web-services, devops, ansible-playbook, ec2

Пытаюсь разобраться с Ansible + AWS.
Есть несложная задача. Создать EC2 instance и поставить на него несколько пакетов.

При помощи amazon.aws в Ansible создал Sequrity Group, Key pair, Instance.
После создания instance я сохраняю результат при помощи:

```
register: ec2
```

Как мне потом выполнять действия на своем новосозданном instance? я же не могу его внести в inventory файл??.
или мне не надо туда его вносить?

или я могу использовать что то типа:

```
- name: Install dependens
  hosts: {{ec2.instances.public_ip_address}}
  tasks: 
    - name: TASK1
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это мне лучше работать.
хочется полностью автомат, а не так, чтобы запустить 1 файл и создать instance. А потом заполнить данными ип в инвентори файл и другим плейбуком делать доп. установки пакетов.

Спасибо

Comment: скорее всего нашел таки, решение.. еще не проверял, завтра уже.. но думаю оно верное.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34394672/getting-the-ip-address-attributes-of-the-aws-instance-created-using-ansible